# Is the fourier transform of a function in two different variables, the same?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ the exact same as the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ when $t$ is related to $x$? For example if $t = x + 5$, would their Fourier transforms be the exact same?

Isn't this expression always true:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i \omega x}dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i \omega t}dt$$

Comment: There's a phase difference.

Comment: @JackyChong What do you mean?

Comment: $x$ and $t$ are dummy variables in either the function expression of $f(\cdot)$ or in the integral.

Comment: Your notation implies that $f(x) = f(t)$, which is not what you want. You instead should put $f(t)$ for one integral and $g(x)$ for the other. No, those integrals are not the same, because you are taking the transform with two different functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+5)e^{-i \omega (x+5)}dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i \omega t}dt$$
Take for example $f(t)=e^t$, then
$$e^{5(1-i\omega)}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^xe^{-i \omega x}dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x+5}e^{-i \omega (x+5)}dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^te^{-i \omega t}dt$$
so the answer is no.